# Own Service: Unable to instantiate receiver

Tags: java, android, service

First of all I have to say that I'm totally newbie on java.
I wrote this using some tutorials.

As you see, the package name is correct in manifest and there aren't misspelling errors...

I'm trying to write a service for my device, which controls the led of it. But I'm keep getting this error:

> AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.gabrielgagz.ledpearlyn.LedPearlynReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/app/LedPearlyn/LedPearlyn.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/app/LedPearlyn/lib/arm, /system/app/LedPearlyn/LedPearlyn.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

LedPearlynReceiver:

```
package com.gabrielgagz.ledpearlyn;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.*;

public class LedPearlynReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STARTED))  {
        try {
        String[] cmd = { "/system/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/pearlyn/brightness"};         
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        } catch(IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        wasScreenOn = false;
        Log.e("LedPearlyn","OFF");
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON) ||  intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STOPPED)) {
        try {
        String[] cmd = { "/system/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 255 > /sys/class/leds/pearlyn/brightness"};       
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        } catch(IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
        } 
        wasScreenOn = true;
        Log.e("LedPearlyn","ON");
    }        
}
}
```

LedPearlynService:

```
package com.gabrielgagz.ledpearlyn;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

public class LedPearlynService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
    }

@Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    }

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STARTED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STOPPED);
    final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new LedPearlynReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    LedPearlynService getService() {
    return LedPearlynService.this;
    }
}
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.gabrielgagz.ledpearlyn" platformBuildVersionCode="25" platformBuildVersionName="7.1.2"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS" />
<application>
    <receiver android:label="LedPearlynReceiver" android:name=".LedPearlynReceiver" android:exported="false"> 
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DREAMING_STARTED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DREAMING_STOPPED" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".LedPearlynService" android:exported="false"></service>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `android:exported="false"`(by default for receivers with intent filters has android:exported = true) from the `LedPearlynReceiver` declaration in Manifest.

Reference : `https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html#exported`

Also, try adding the fully qualified name in the manifest.
`android:name="com.gabrielgagz.ledpearlyn.LedPearlynReceiver"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still have the same problem even with the olution you provided...

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Well finally i don't know if your solution works, or this did the trick (i'm writing this for a Lineage custom rom): cyanogenmod.permission.BIND_CORE_SERVICEThanks